# Mounting shm in Docker container without --privileged option

Tags: docker, shared-memory

How to mount /dev/shm in a container without using the --privileged option?

Comment: 4GB of shared memory is required, not the default 65536k

Comment: I guess that's not possible yet: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/4981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Engine supports `--shm-size` flag since v1.10.